# Store peer service credentials securely in IBM WebSphere Application server

Tags: java, spring, websphere, java-ee-7

There is a Java application (spring) deployed in the WebSphere application server. That application calls APIs exposed by other applications/services (Ex: web services). So it needs to store the credentials for those services that it is calling somewhere securely. Currently, the credentials are stored in .properties files which I think is not secure enough. Is there a mechanism provided by WebSphere application server to store the credentials in the application server and inject those to the applications running inside? Or is there another way that is better than storing the credentials inside .properties files? I couldn't find a direct way to do that in the official documentation.